# How to prevent liquid backflow when pumping an upside-down liquid container with air to pressurize it?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, valves

I'm trying to design a system that will have glass bottles upside down filled with liquid. They will be pressurized via a bulkhead air input and will dispense through bulkhead liquid output.

[Here is a crude drawing of the system concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEfC3.png)

The bulkheads are 1/4" Push-to-Connect fittings, I asked a mechE friend if i could simply use a [one-way check valve like these](https://a.co/d/2ySZMTk) in between the bulkhead and the air pump but he said there will likely still be backflow issues (he didn't elaborate why).

What is the standard method for preventing backflow for system like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do these push-to-connect water filters activate water flow once pushed in?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/55032/how-do-these-push-to-connect-water-filters-activate-water-flow-once-pushed-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious/common method would be a rigid tube sticking up above the water line:

[image]

Air inlet on the left, liquid outlet on the right. If (for whatever reason) you prefer not to use rigid tubing, a sufficient length of flexible tubing with a float on the end is also sometimes used.

Obviously neither of these works if the bottle will start out entirely full. For a case like that, another common possibility is to have the air fill a bladder that can expand to (at least nearly) fill the bottle. As the simplest version, consider simply a child's birthday balloon. When you blow air in, the balloon inflates, filling the bottle.

One more common possibility is to simply put the air pump well above the top of the bottle, or at least loop the hose outside the bottle up well above the water line (far enough to assure that if the pump stops, it won't form a siphon).

Comment: thanks for your answers! I do not want to do the air line extending down the entire length of the bottle for aesthetic reasons, similarly with a air bladder (thought that is a neat idea). I don't think i'm able to put the air pump above the liquid, but i *might* be able to if i design it right. Its a hard balance for aesthetic and functional tradeoffs.