# How do these push-to-connect water filters activate water flow once pushed in?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, flow-control

I'm looking for a mechanism I can employ so that I can pull liquid containing bottles that are upside down out of a system, fill it, put the cap (with mechanism) back on. Then be able to turn the bottle upside down and push it back into the system to allow liquid flow. I want it to not leak anything until i push it into the main unit.

Basically, a combination bulkhead+valve that where the valve is activated by connecting the bulkhead on one side.

I realized I've seen a "push to connect" bulkhead thingie like this before. My water filter in my fridge pushes in to start the water flow. How does it do this? What kind of bulkhead fitting is on it. [Some pictures of it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE6hB.jpg)

How does it work, presumably the water is ready to go on the other side and doesn't flow until you push in this unit which is horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often a spring loaded ball valve that is opened as the unit gets pushed into its final location.

The spring pressure may be light as the system pressure can also be part of holding the valve closed, however if the system pressure is significant there can be a pressure balance across the valve.

Comment: interesting, i'll need to think about how i could incorporate a spring-loaded ball valve into my design. Is there more where i can read about how the valve is opened when depressed? When i search "spring loaded ball valve" they seem like closed systems that dont react to something being inserted